# How to save multiple objects to CoreData, under a single name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I'm working on a project in swift 3.0 where I have a UITableView with multiple selection option (each row has a URL). Thus, on top of the TableView use can enter a name in a textfield. My requirement is once these rows are been selected the data should get saved in coredata under the typed name. As of now the data get saved as individual elements, so I have troubles with clustering data under its name. How could I achieve this ??. The method that I save and extract data as bellow.

save

```
public static func savePlaylistDetails(audio:AudioDetails, playListName: String) {

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let newPlaylist = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: PlayList_DETAILS_ENTITY, into: context)


newPlaylist.setValue(playListName, forKey:"playlistName");
newPlaylist.setValue(audio.mediaId, forKey:"trackID");

do{
    try context.save();
    print("Saved.....")
}
catch{
    print("There was an error")
}
```

}

extract the saved Data

```
public static func getPlayList() -> [PlayListDetails]?{
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: PlayList_DETAILS_ENTITY)
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

do{
    let results = try context.fetch(request)
    if(results.count > 0 ){
        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
            let playListDetails:PlayListDetails? = result as? PlayListDetails
            print("Title: \(playListDetails?.playlistName)")


        }
        return results as? [PlayListDetails]
    }else{
        print("No results")
    }

}catch{
    print("Error in fetching items")
}
return nil;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In general you should create another entity which stores all the data for a single input. In your case this looks like a single string. After you have done so you need to create a relationship which in your case should be one-to-many or even many-to-many. You can easily do that in the core data interface builder. In one-to-many case you will most likely need to remove the previous entries from the database or you will have a leak. In many to many you need to track uniques by ID or by content.

But there are alternatives. The most simple one would be to to create some kind of marker, a separator of strings to pack all the strings into a single one. For instance to serialize it you would use something like:

```
let fullString = ((results as? [PlayListDetails]).flatMap { $0.name })?.joined(separator: "-@;@-")
```

Then to deserialize it you would use:

```
let names = fullString.components(separatedBy: "-@;@-")
```

If you are sure these are the only data you need then this is enough but if you anticipate other fields you may use transformable data instead of string and insert a JSON. You would serialize it as:

```
let jsonArray: [[String: Any]] = results.flatMap { ["name": $0.name, "id": $0.id] }
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

And deserialize it as:

```
let playlistDetails: [PlayListDetails]? = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]])?.flatMap { PlayListDetails(name: $0["name"] as? String, id: $0["id"] as? String) }
```